# 1990 Ford F-150 5.0 no start just clicks

Tags: ford, starting, f-150

I was driving down the highway at 60 mph with no warning the truck shuts off so i coast to the shoulder.

It did not over heat or lose oil pressure.

When i try to start it back up it just clicked with no crank, left it overnight came back in the morning, went to try it and it cranked over almost started. Went to try it again and it just clicked every since then.

Comment: Welcome Shawn!  Can you proofread your question to make it more readable?  Adding punctuation, such as periods, would be a helpful start!

Answer (score 2):

First step is to disconnect battery, fully charge it and have it tested. Clean battery cables (both ends of both cables) and battery terminals. Put good battery in. Start your truck and put a voltmeter to your battery. You should see 13.5 to 14.5 volts. If you do, drive on. If you don't, have charging system checked.

Comment: I bought a new battery replaced battery cables

Comment: Clicking is usually caused by either a discharged battery, or a bad cable, or a bad cable connection.  When did you buy the new battery and cables...before or after the events recited in your question? Also...forgive me...it'd be a lot easier to read what you've written if you would use commas and periods and standard capitalization.